# Repeatedly erroring in eclipse when building Angular application

Tags: angular, eclipse

When tried compile it throws this error. Pm file looks like at the below.   I have changed version of the node release and it does change error code.  I think now the issue is that one of the angular module is not being important.  By the way i am very new to angular but end up fixing this code.
Thanks in advance for you help.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --------------------< com.tristatehc:tristatehcApp >--------------------
    [INFO] Building tristatehcApp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ tristatehcApp ---
    [INFO] Node v12.22.7 is already installed.
    [INFO] NPM 3.10.8 is already installed.
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm install) @ tristatehcApp ---
    [INFO] Running 'npm install angular2-datetimepicker' in C:\Users\tristate1005\git\tush2\tristatehcApp012019\src\main\webapp\tristatehc-app
    [ERROR] npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\tristate1005\git\tush2\tristatehcApp012019\src\main\webapp\tristatehc-app\node_modules\angular2-datetimepicker
    [ERROR] npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.22000
    [ERROR] npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\tristate1005\\git\\tush2\\tristatehcApp012019\\node_installation\\node\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\tristate1005\\git\\tush2\\tristatehcApp012019\\node_installation\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "angular2-datetimepicker"
    [ERROR] npm ERR! node v12.22.7
    [ERROR] npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
    [ERROR] npm ERR! path C:\Users\tristate1005\git\tush2\tristatehcApp012019\src\main\webapp\tristatehc-app\node_modules\angular2-datetimepicker
    [ERROR] npm ERR! code ENOENT
    [ERROR] npm ERR! errno -4058
    [ERROR] npm ERR! syscall open
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\tristate1005\git\tush2\tristatehcApp012019\src\main\webapp\tristatehc-app\node_modules\angular2-datetimepicker'
    [ERROR] npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\tristate1005\git\tush2\tristatehcApp012019\src\main\webapp\tristatehc-app\node_modules\angular2-datetimepicker'
    [ERROR] npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
    [ERROR] npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    [ERROR] npm ERR! enoent 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    [ERROR] npm ERR!     C:\Users\tristate1005\git\tush2\tristatehcApp012019\src\main\webapp\tristatehc-app\npm-debug.log
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 14.479 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-11T11:00:21-04:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm install) on project : Failed to run task: 'npm install angular2-datetimepicker' failed. (error code -4058) -> [Help 1]enter code here
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException





    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>com.tristatehc</groupId>
        <artifactId>tristatehcApp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
    
        <name>tristatehcApp</name>
        <description>Trisatehc Web application</description>
    
    
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
    
    
    
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <angular.project.location>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/tristatehc-app</angular.project.location>
            <angular.project.nodeinstallation>node_installation</angular.project.nodeinstallation>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>${angular.project.location}</workingDirectory>
                        <installDirectory>${angular.project.nodeinstallation}</installDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
            
                        <execution>
                            <id>install node and npm</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
        <!-- <nodeVersion>v10.0.0</nodeVersion> -->                     
                                <nodeVersion>v12.22.7</nodeVersion>
            <!--                    <npmVersion>3.10.8</npmVersion>
             -->                    <npmVersion>3.10.8</npmVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
        <!--    -->
                        <!-- It will execute command "npm install" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install angular2-datetimepicker</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        
                        <!-- It will execute command "npm build" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory 
                            to clean and create "/dist" directory -->
                        <execution> 
                            <id>npm build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>run build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
    
    
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>target/tristatehc-app</directory>
                    <targetPath>static</targetPath>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    
    
    </project>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the `npm-debug.log` file, or rerun the build with `-e` as it mentions in the output? What was shown there and then?

Comment: Well thanks for the response.  how do i do it?    I mean i have to change the pom.xml? if it is then which line. And i did look at the log file and could not make out of this anything.